# Is there a way to test Blockchain.info APIs?

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I'm trying to set up Blockchain.info web APIs to notify me when I
receive a BTC payment:
https://www.blockchain.com/api/api_receive

So say, if I generate a receiving address as such:

```
https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=<my_xpub>&callback=<callback_url>&key=<my_key>
```

Can I somehow test how my `callback_url` will be called?

PS. Sorry, I'm new to this. Before when I was dealing with a fiat currency, PayPal for instance had a developer portal where you can send yourself a test web API request.